# How to query all array elements with specific value from a single record in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following Schema in Mongoose and I want to make a database query on the following schema:

```
const History = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, index: true, unique: true },
  history: [{
    ex: { type: Number, index: true },
    date: { type: String },
    time: { type: Number },
  }],
});
```

I want to query for a specific `username` and then within that record I only want the history records where `ex: 4` for example. I've been able to get a single entry back like this:

```
History.find({ username: 'testuser', 'history.ex': 4 }, { 'history.$': 1 }, callback);
```

In other words. I want to retrieve a single document of which its attribute array `history` is only a selection of all its history items, as I want to only have objects from that array which have e.g. `ex:4`.

Comment: This is a different question as I'm also querying a specific document, whereas in the suggested duplicated question there's is only interest for the array items.

Comment: Ok fixed it like this:
`History.aggregate({ $match: { username: 'testuser' } }, { $unwind: '$history' }, { $match: { 'history.ex': 4) } }, { $project: { username: 1, history: { ex: 1, date: 1 } } }, callback);`